# LEGACY MYSQL SETUP Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory

Tags: php, mysql, php-5.6

Fellow Developers,
I have solved the initial issue, but if anyone has a docker image that would run this, i would much appreciate it.
I need help with a very old app.

I am setting up a VM environment for an old application. Please read through carefully if you intend to help.

I have an old application that is soon to be thrown away as we are working on the rewrite, however the old application still needs to be supported and it runs very old version of PHP and MYSQL. The code below is supposed to test that the db connection works.

```
require_once("/var/www/html/class/autoload.php");
$database = $_ENV['DB_HOST'];
$DBuser = $_ENV["MYSQL_USER"];
$DBpass = $_ENV["MYSQL_USER"];
$link = mysql_connect($database, $DBuser, $DBpass, null);

if (!$link) {
    echo "Error: Unable to connect to MySQL." . PHP_EOL;
    echo "Debugging errno: " . mysql_error() . PHP_EOL;
    exit;
}
```

The code breaks giving me

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory in /var/www/html/docker_build/test_db.php on line 10
Error: Unable to connect to MySQL. Debugging errno: No such file or directory
```

If in the same code block i use `mysqli_connect` istead everything works, but the project runs on mysql_functions. The app works on the staging and production servers and i tried to copy the setup on my VM, also here is the dockerfile that used to work, but recently some security updates stopped it from working.

```
version: "3"

services:
  webserver:
    build: 
      context: ${DOCKER_BUILD_ROOT}/bin/${DOCKER_PHPVERSION}
    container_name: ${DOCKER_PHPVERSION}
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_UNSECURE_HOST_PORT}:80"
      - "${HOST_MACHINE_SECURE_HOST_PORT}:443"
    links: 
      - database
    volumes: 
      - ${DOCUMENT_ROOT-.}:/var/www/html
      - ${PHP_INI-./docker_build/config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - ${VHOSTS_DIR-./docker_build/config/vhosts}:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
      - ${APACHE_LOG_DIR-./docker_build/logs/apache2}:/var/log/apache2
    # user: "1000:1000"
    user: root
  database:
    build:
      context: "${DOCKER_BUILD_ROOT}/bin/${DOCKER_DATABASE}"
    container_name: 'database'
    restart: 'always'
    ports:
      - "${DOCKER_LOCALHOST}:${HOST_MACHINE_MYSQL_PORT}:3306"
    volumes: 
      - ${MYSQL_CONF_FILE-./docker_build/config/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf}:/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf
      - ${MYSQL_DATA_DIR-./docker_build/data/mysql}:/var/lib/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_LOG_DIR-./docker_build/logs/mysql}:/var/log/mysql
      - ${MYSQL_INIT_DIR-./docker_build/config/mysql/ini}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    container_name: 'phpmyadmin'
    links:
      - database
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: database
      PMA_PORT: 3306
      PMA_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      PMA_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - '8080:80'
    volumes: 
      - /sessions
      - ${PHP_INI-./docker_build/config/php/php.ini}:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-phpmyadmin.ini
  redis:
    container_name: 'redis'
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - "${DOCKER_LOCALHOST}:${HOST_MACHINE_REDIS_PORT}:6380"
```

```
FROM php:5.6-apache

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y

# Install tools && libraries
RUN apt-get -y install --fix-missing apt-utils nano wget dialog \
    build-essential git curl libcurl3 libcurl3-dev zip \
    libmcrypt-dev libsqlite3-dev libsqlite3-0 mysql-client \
    zlib1g-dev libicu-dev libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev libpng-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

# PHP5 Extensions

RUN docker-php-ext-install curl \
    && docker-php-ext-install tokenizer \
    && docker-php-ext-install json \
    && docker-php-ext-install mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo_sqlite \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysql \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) intl \
    && docker-php-ext-install mbstring \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && pecl install xdebug-2.5.5 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

# Enable apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite headers

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    mediainfo \
    jhead \
    imagemagick \
    ffmpeg

RUN usermod -u 1000 www-data

EXPOSE 80

# initialize server script. designed to be run after volumes are mounted.
# runs composer install and runs apache2 foreground.
# ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/sbin/apache2ctl", "-D", "FOREGROUND"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker_build/config/server_ini.sh"]
```

All i need is to get this up and running. If it can be done with docker that would be perfect but i think that image is long deprecated. Any help is very much appreciated. I can provide you with the env and .ini setup. I didnt want to pase too much in the question.

I tried everything, i looked throught .ini and .env and all the linux setup. looks like mysql socket is not setting up properly, however the cmd connection works fine `mysql -uroot -p` works fine

Comment: Are you aware that PHP 5.6 has been unsupported since December 2018? You should be using PHP 8.1 or 8.2 for current projects. See https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: Hope this port works out as the longer this goes, the harder it gets.

Comment: I was able to update an app from a super old version of PHP a few years ago. I used JetBrains PhpStorm, which has some features to do code analysis and identifies places in your code that will need to be changed for an upgrade. I recommend using this kind of tool, even if it costs a few hundred dollars. That is far less expensive than the hours or days of a software engineer's time to do the same analysis manually and debug the code when it doesn't work.

Comment: @BillKarwin yes and i specifically said that we are working on the rewrite

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being a typo thing. i had to update my `.env` and instead of `DB_HOST="localhost:3306"` i had to put `DB_HOST="127.0.0.1:3306"`  and it worked. Hope this helps anyone